# AWS Lambda can't receive file from an Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a CDK in C# .NET Core 3.1, that will create an Amazon S3 Bucket, a lambda role, a lambda and a lambda destination notification for the S3 Bucket. Whenever I put an object into the Amazon S3 Bucket the lambda will start it's magic.
Now to the part where I am stuck. When I locally test the lambda everything is working dandily. I am receiving the notification, my lambda is reading the S3 Bucketname and the Object Name and I will get the response stream by calling GetObjectAsync. However the Lambda always has this error in the logs:

```
Error getting object xxx.zip from bucket txxx. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.
```

Both are correct. I am also using the Method _s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async to see if it can find the object and it can.
If you are wondering if the IAM role for the lambda is the one causing the issue:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*",
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the policy assosiated with it.
Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?
Kind regards

Comment: What is the code that generates the error?

Comment: ```_response = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(s3Event.S3.Bucket.Name, s3Event.S3.Object.Key)```

Comment: afterwards I use this _response in that way: ```using (var archive = new ZipArchive(_response.ResponseStream))
            {
                archive.ExtractToDirectory(basePath);
            }
``` But it never reaches this code.
It's always a Zip that is uploaded and basePath is "/tmp/Application/"

Comment: The lambda function and the bucket are in the same region?

Comment: Yes both are in eu-central-1!

Comment: You can edit the question and add full code.  Also have you confirmed that `s3Event.S3.Bucket.Name` and key contain correct values?

Comment: Please update your answer to include a couple of other areas . In your AWS environment is the lambda deployed to a VPC if so are you sure it not in a public subnet?, do you run AWS endpoints for S3 traffic inside of your VPC if so you are probably missing a security group set between the two.  Sounds like you have a AWS permission issue rather than code issue.